# How to calculate or define moving expenses for California resident tax deduction?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, state-income-tax, california, moving

Situation:

I meet the distance & time test for California Moving Expenses Deduction. Move was within California, in 2021. Single person household. The distance one way is 181 miles, using own vehicle. No reimbursement from employer. Storage at old city was free for first month. I am using form FTB 3913. Have miles log written.

I drove to new with my super essential things (toiletries, some work clothes, some food etc), 181 miles, got hotel for two night, reported to work at morning & later signed the rental agreement next day. Rental was not ready, extended hotel for one more (third) night. Hotel & Rental & New work are in same city.

- Q1. Is any of these hotel nights deductible on Line 02?
- Q2. Are these above miles deductible as Line 02? `(Travel (including lodging) from your old home to your new home)`

After 4 days, on weekend morning, drove back to old city, & brought majority of things, car was full, still had to leave some back. Drove 181*2 miles, return same day. Have fuel receipts.

- Q3. Can I deduct these driven miles at same rate as Q2 on Line 01, as `(Transportation and storage of household goods and personal effects)`; or do I have to use fuel receipts only?

I did one more last trip to pick the last boxes, & clean & surrender the keys for storage, same as above. That was the last trip.

- Q4. Same as Q3.

Thanks,